# Pixel 2 Android Phone to Lenovo Windows 10 Bluetooth Won't Pair

Tags: windows, lenovo, bluetooth-pairing, google-pixel-2

My Pixel 2 Android phone WILL NOT pair via Bluetooth with my Lenovo ThinkPad Windows 10 laptop PC.  I have tried everything including uninstalling antivirus/firewall software on both devices.  Neither device detects the other device over Bluetooth.  Both devices detect all other in-range Bluetooth devices.  I have disabled the AirDroid app on my phone.  Of course both devices have Bluetooth enabled via their respective Settings selections.  I am at my wits end and want some help fast.  I am about to conclude that Microsoft Bluetooth doesn't want to talk to Google Bluetooth and vice versa despite the fact that Bluetooth is an open standard accepted throughout the industry.  Are there additional steps that need to be taken in order to make both devices "discoverable"?  I tried to install a Microsoft app on my Android phone in order to establish a Bluetooth link but the app wanted to take over my phone and I decided not to go through with the installation.  Any advice on this matter is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there additional steps that need to be taken in order to make both devices "discoverable"?

Yes. Android phones are discoverable only while the Bluetooth Settings activity is displayed. (There's a message in the activity to tell you this.) You need to scan for devices from your laptop while this activity is open on your phone.